# Partitioning in Spark 3.1 with java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using spark 3.1 with java. In my code, I am writing final result dataset into GCP storage, in that it creates multiple files as my dataset is large. I am spark job in GCP dataproc cluster. It is configured to use 250 worker nodes(each has 8 vCPUs). Spark command is configured to run 2 executers per node and 3 cores for each executor. When the spark job is trigger YARN ResourceManager is showing only 25% of worker cores being used to containers per node. Also I configured, shuffle partition size as 5500(spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5500). And I used

`mydataset.coalesce(4500)` to reduce the number of result files creating in Cloud stoage. But it creates 5499 files for one of the dataset which has nearly 45000 rows and 3500 files for another dataset which has nearly 85000 rows. Its really confusing on what basis its creating file partition s. Can't I control that? Is there any default value there? If yes, can i get that default value in Java code?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What happens if you use `mydataset.repartition(4500, <column with nicely distributed data>`) instead of `coalesce`?

Comment: You can print the actual num of partitions before writing to GCS. Usually one partition will result in one file.